# Performance & Memory Footprint of Java Logging , Log4J , Logback

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j, logback, java.util.logging

I know, currently most suitable combination is SLF4J + Logback, however considering my requirement is very basic logging, my simple questions are

1>   Performance & memory foot print wise which one is better between Java Logging & Log4J and why ?

2>   Performance & memory foot print wise which one is better between Java Logging &  (SLF4J + Logback) and why ?

Comment: Considering your requirement that should be irrelevant. Logback is highly optimized to minimize resource waste on suppressed log statements (those below the configured threshold). JUL is, well, basic, with no particular optimizations.

Comment: Best way to find out: write a test. If you can't get a test working then SO might be a good place to ask for answers to specific problems arising from such a test.

Comment: Best performance requires in-memory caching.  You need to be very explicit about how you measure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> considering my requirement is very basic logging

Then you should only worry about simplicitly.  Java Logging is likely to be the simplest solution and its performance is likely to be okay.

The memory footprint of most loggers isn't an issue.  Sometimes performance is, but unless you have a low latency (sub milli-second) or high throughput (thousands of logged events per second) system, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Problem with logging performance is that you normally want to be sure that all is logged when your program crashes.  If anything is still in a buffer and not persisted you cannot see it.

Comment: In that case the more performant and complex solution which uses buffering or asynchronous logging is actually a disadvantage if you have a sudden crash. I prefer to use memory mapped files which are synchronous and have a very low latency (and are not lost an application crash). But I wouldn't call them the simplest. ;)

Comment: Having only recently been able to even _consider_ Java 6 in production this is largely unknown territory to me.   What would you suggest looking into for logback or java.util.logging?

Comment: Given Java 6 will be EOL in Nov this year (it is 5.5 years old), perhaps you could consider moving to Java 7. ;) Without more details I would stick with the simplest which IMHO is the built in.  Logback has some advantages, but you might not really benefit from them.

Comment: IBM has a completely different lifespan of their Java products on non-x86 platforms, so our default target is Java 5.  For research do you have any good links to memory mapping files in this scenario?

Comment: You could look at mine ;) https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Chronicle and my blog http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/how-much-difference-can-thread-affinity.html

Answer (score 3):

"Very basic logging" usually isn't.

Where will log entries go?  If in files, what about saving log files instead of overwriting at restart?  What will happen to stale saved log files?

I would recommend that you use slf4j for the API in your own code. And, unless you have other modules or politics enforcing a specific solution, I would suggest logback since it is the most actively maintained at the moment and you can replace it later with log4j or jul if needed.

Also, slf4j gives you {} which is the singlemost improvement to logging in the client I've seen so far.

Answer (score 2):

I could give you the following advice: unless you're doing something just for fun, it's very probable your code will expand and you'll have to rewrite all log statements to a production-quality API. If that's the case, I suggest you use SLF4J, which still leaves you the choice to use JUL, Log4j, or logback.